# Loading and unloading a .js file conditionally on browser window resize event

Tags: javascript, html

*Use case #1:*
The following demo, will load a zooming feature to images if the browser width is greater than 500px.

https://codepen.io/zuhocuyixu/pen/NYLZrY

```
 <!-- Loading .js file with Head.js
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/headjs/1.0.3/head.js"></script>
        <script>
          if (window.innerWidth > 500) {
            head.ready(document, function() {
              head.load('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zooming/1.4.2/zooming.js', function() {
                   var ZoomingIsLoaded = true;   
                   var zooming = new Zooming();
                   zooming.listen('.value-img');
                   });
              });
            }
          else {
            var ZoomingIsLoaded = false;
          }
        </script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
      var myVar="ReCheckIfZoomingShouldBeLoaded";
        function ReCheckIfZoomingShouldBeLoaded() {
          if (window.innerWidth > 500 && ZoomingIsLoaded == false) {
                    head.ready(document, function() {
                      head.load('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zooming/1.4.2/zooming.js', function() {
                           var zooming = new Zooming();
                           zooming.listen('.value-img');
                           var ZoomingIsLoaded = true;
                           });
                      });
          }
        }
    </script>
```

*Use case #2:*
If the width is less than 500px it will not load the zooming, although on browser resize it will check if the width has become greater than 500px and then load the zooming feature.

The issue is that once it loads the zooming features it is buggy and acts strange when closing it.

Any ideas how to fix this glitch?

Also if anyone has an idea how to unload the zooming feature if the browser width goes below 500px, that would be of great help.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to make zooming 'unlisten' ?

Comment: You should load the zooming library only once, at the beginning. If then, the user resize, listen on resize event and apply or not the zooming.listen when necessary, as far as I can see .listen() will also remove the listener when needed.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I try to load the .js in the beginning and only call zooming.listen on certain conditions checked on resize, although I cannot make the code to work. My coding experience is quite limited. Any advice on how to achieve this?